# jquery addClass() to enable a button as a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On page load, I have a class attached to a bootstrap `<button>` called `.link-active` that I use to make the `<button>` act like a link with this script:

```
$('.link-active').click(function(){
window.location='foo.php';
});
```

However, when I successfully remove the `.link-active` class using `removeClass()`, the button continues to act like a link when clicked and takes me to `foo.php` even when the class isn't on there. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: please don't use javascript links. Users cannot open them in new tab. I would recommend wrapping button in <a> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to removing the class you should also remove the event:

```
$('.link-active').off('click');
```

Or use chaining:

```
$('.link-active').off('click').removeClass('link-active');
```

The reason it continues to work is because the attached event already has a reference to the element its attached to. It doesn't query the DOM every time. If you don't want to remove the event you could use event delegation to attach the event and then it would work the way you imagine.

```
$('body').on('click', '.link-active', someFunction);
```

Comment: I've got the first part working. The event is a `select` and when I choose something other than the first choice that I see on page load, I am using this to remove the class and make the button not act like a link: `$('#b1').removeClass('link-active').off('click');` however what if I use the select to return to the default? If I try the opposite it does not work: `$('#b1').addClass('link-active').on('click');`

Comment: @TripleC you I'll need to pass the function you want to run if you attach the event again. .on('click', function () { window.location = "foo.php" });